# Rotating 3x3 matrix

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

Can anyone help me rotate my 3x3 matrix by multiplying it to another matrix (matrix multiplication). The matrix is coming from the `vector.txt` file. I need help in rotating this matrix in terms of matrix multiplication.

I'm just a student so please bear with me if my code isn't good.

It was a previous requirement for us, but I wasn't able to get it, but I want to learn how to do it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    cout << "Loading vector.txt" << endl;
    FILE *file = fopen("vector.txt", "r");
    int vector[3];
    int b = 0;

    do {
        fscanf(file, "%i", &vector[b]);
        b++;
    } while (feof(file) == 0);

    //clear the screen.
    fclose(file);

    cout << "Loading matrix" << endl;

    int a[3][3] = {}, y, x;
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            a[0][y] = vector[y];
    }

    //Display the original matrix
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            cout << a[y][x] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //Scale by two
    cout << "Scale of original matrix is: " << endl;
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (x = y * 4; x < 3; x++) {
            cout << a[y][x] * (2) << endl;
        }
    }

    //Display the transpose matrix
    cout << "Transpose of original matrix is: " << endl;
    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            if (a[y][x] != 0)
                cout << a[y][x] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Nice homework assignment ;-)

Comment: Actually the homework was a lot longer and the submission was over a few hours ago. :)

Comment: Questions: 1) What does `getch()` do?  Dare I ask?  2) Do you actually use `#include<conio.h>` ?  3) Can you post a sample `vector.txt` file? 4) Can you tell us what your expected output is, and what you are getting instead?

Comment: What are you doing with nested loops after this line `cout << "Loading matrix" << endl;` ?

Comment: 1.) it's just for getting character just to show the output in a console window. 2.) Yeah so that parts of my line won't be undefined. 3.) I want the vector to rotate 0 0 3 
                                           0 2 0
                                           1 0 0

Comment: That turns the items in my vector.txt (which has 1 2 3 digits in it) into a matrix like this. 1 2 3 but I want it to be 1 0 0
                         0 0 0                     0 2 0
                         0 0 0                     0 0 3

Comment: What you have done , is `1 2 3 , 0 0 0 , 0 0 0` not `1 0 0 , 2 0 0 , 3 0 0` + you don't need to create 3x3 matrix to transpose it ? you can do it 3x1 (you need only 1 column).

Comment: Yes sorry my bad, the spacing was wrong when I was typing the comment. I just need to know how to rotate it through matrix multiplication, because I already know matrix multiplication. But i don't know how to implement it into my code

Answer (score 1):

Your program can be improved in lots of places. However, I am going to focus on the question you asked in the first line of your question:

> Can anyone help me rotate my 3x3 matrix by multiplying it to another matrix

Problem:

You only have one matrix in your function, `a`.

1. You need a second matrix to perform a matrix multiplication.
2. You need a third matrix to store the result of the multiplication.

Let's say you come up with:

```
int b[3][3];
int c[3][3];
```

and want to compute `c = a * b`.

You need to a nested for loop to compute the matrix multiplication.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
  {
     c[i][j] = 0;
     for ( int k = 0; k < 3; ++k )
     {
        c[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
     }
  }
}
```